# How to merge sequences in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I am trying to remove some redundancy in setting up several tasks within GitLab CI. As a (greatly) simplified example, I have two jobs involving a call to `apt-get update`:

```
job1:
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install foo

job2:
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install bar
```

Not being a big fan of repetitions, I hoped that I would be able to "clean up" the yaml through the help of [anchors](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/yaml/README.md#anchors) as follows:

```
.update: &update
  before_script:
    - apt-get update

job1:
  <<: *update
  before_script:
    - apt-get install foo

job2:
  <<: *update
  before_script:
    - apt-get install bar
```

However, it appears that the `before_script` stanzas are not merged with `*update`. Instead, I find latter one being *overwritten*. This is in contrast to the GitLab CI docs as well as the example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Advanced_components), though.

Through some experimentation, I managed to get the following to run:

```
.update: &update apt-get update

job1:
  before_script: 
    - *update
    - apt-get install foo

job2:
  before_script: 
    - *update
    - apt-get install bar
```

Clearly a step forward. But given that I intend to go for more complex substitutions, this is hardly satisfactory. For reference: This is on GitLab v 8.12.

Comment: The appropriate terminology for YAML is **scalar** (string, int, float, date, boolean), **mapping** (dict, hash) and **sequence** (list, array?). The wikipedia example has an explicit comment "redefines just this key, refers rest from &id001", so there is no contrast with the behaviour you see. Do you have a link to the Gitlab docs where the merge is explained?

Comment: Link to the GitLab docs is in the question. Sorry for the confusion in terms: looks like I was actually looking to merge *sequences*.

Comment: Sorry, had not been looking that far back in the post. Neither the gitlab doc nor the wikipedia page mentions merging multiple aliases using `<<: [*alias1, *alias2, *alias3]` That doesn't help with the sequences, but lets you combine pre-defined anchored mappings in different ways.

Comment: ... which would not really be what I wanted. But I really appreciate your continued efforts to provide a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what the `<<:` merge does. It pre-fills the mapping that it is part of, with the key-value pairs from the anchored mapping. And any keys that follow the merge are added to that mapping, with the value for a key that already existed in one of the merged mappings being overwritten with that value. [Here](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) is the documentation.

There is no such thing as appending of sequences in YAML, such as you describe in your expectations. The merge is at the level of the keys, not recursively (not for mapping, nor for sequences)

Comment: In other words: I can merge hashes but not lists? That were most unfortunate.

Comment: You can merge mappings, which is what you were doing. You seem to assume that is some recursive action, which it is not. Apart from that I do not know how to apply the verb *merge* to two sequences (since they are ordered), if by that you mean *append* then no, there is no such functionality, recursive or not. Since you don't have keys in a sequence, it would require ugly syntax to distinguish a normal aliased element and one with special interpretation (i.e. what is done by overloading the `<<` scalar as key in a mapping).

Comment: It is of course entirely possible to implement what you want using tags, but that would need resolving at the level of the code reading the YAML.

Comment: Well, I mostly looked for a way to take redundancy out of those lists in the `before_script` key. Recursive merging would have made that easier to read, but I do not see it as absolute requirement. Anyhow, looks like I'd have to live with the repetition for the time being.

Comment: I used to dislike this limitation but I've found that in practice, there is almost always a clean way to refactor between before_script, script, and also moving some bits of script to helper .sh files. Just note that when you do the .sh files part, you'll want to do `set -euo pipefail` for similar "strict mode" that exits immediately upon errors.

Comment: Apparently there is also now [a feature for GitLab YAML reuse, called `include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include). Though, it is an upgrade feature.

Comment: There is an open issue for this on the GitLab issue tracker: [gitlab-ci.yaml anchor concatenation in script or after_script](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24235). It would work if GitLab automatically flattened nested lists in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration file.

Comment: To whom it may concern: Gitlab v11.3 introduced the [`extends`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#extends) keyword which is pretty close to what I originally looked for in functionality. However, I have come to adopt @hangtwenty's standpoint in the meantime.

Answer (score 36):

GitLab 13.9 added [`!reference`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) keyword:

```yaml
.setup:
  before_script: apt-get update

job1:
  before_script: 
    - !reference [.setup, before_script]
    - apt-get install foo

job2:
  before_script: 
    - !reference [.setup, before_script]
    - apt-get install bar
```

The union of `reference` and [`extend`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) is really good and will help you battle redundancy.